# Obtain a table name used after executing JDBC Insert/Update/Delete

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Our application executes Insert/Update/Delete SQL's provided to us by our users.  We do not know what the SQL looks like before hand. Does there exist a way to obtain which table was affected after executing the Insert/Update/Delete without parsing the tablename out of the SQL itself?

Note: Obviously, since we are calling `stmt.executeUpdate()` no `ResultSet`/`ResultSetMetaData` will be available to us.

Question: Does there exist a way to determine which table was affected after executing an Insert/Update/Delete SQL?

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on your specific DB system but here are some ideas:

If you can get the table for a column, then you could iterate over all the columns and store the table used.

If you have a connection object you an inspect all tables:

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

If you have access to the SQL query then you can scan for the `FROM` SQL keyword to identify the table, and/or scan the statement further or use an SQL analyzer on the statement.

Comment: Scanning/Parsing is not an option.  How do you iterate over all the columns in a Delete SQL?